# Debugging TypeScript in Firebug

Tags: debugging, firefox, firebug, typescript

Is there any instruction how to debug typescript in Firebug and/or built-in Firefox js-debugger? 
Something [like](http://www.aaron-powell.com/web/typescript-source-maps)  but for Firebug and/or Firefox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) allows debugging of TypeScript code.
The only thing missing is syntax highlighting.

Comment: After trying both normal and Developer Edition Firefox, at least at this point, there's not much difference in debugging Typescript locally. Both behaved pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome canary supports this:
http://www.aaron-powell.com/web/typescript-source-maps

Comment: Although this answer is a little bit off topic, it provides good value by showing another option. I was using Firebug myself, but might be willing to switch to Chrome Canary for debugging TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug is closely integrated with the Javascript execution engine of Firefox. As long as Firefox or Firebug have no support for Typescript I guess you are out of luck.

For Coffeescript, there is [AceBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/acebug/) which offers debugging support for Coffeescript. It should be possible to extend this to TypeScript. However, the structure of the source Typescript and the compiled Javascript can be quite different so the compiler would need to insert debug symbols to link Javascript to Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug version 3.0](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug.next) is being designed to run on top of the built-in debugger in Firefox. This means it also leverages the support for source maps and so the .ts files are loaded correctly.

You can try out preview releases from http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/3.0/

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Firebug (2.0.13 + FF43) seems to be debugging typescript just fine. At least it worked for me so far.

On the web page you add the "compiled" **.js** with a reference to the source map. I.e.

```
<script src="register.js"></script>
```

And Firebug will show you the **register.ts** file instead in the list of scripts instead.

Make sure you have the source map generation on in your tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "sourceMap": true
},
```