# Typescript and Web Console in Firefox

Tags: firefox, typescript

I wrote a web page using Angular 2 and Typescript. When I opened Firefox Web Console, and I tried to find the .ts file in order to debug it, all I found is the Javascript file that was 'transpiled' from the original .ts file.

In Chrome, it's possible to see the Typescript file in the Developer Tools and debug it. Is it also possible in FF ?

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836494/debugging-typescript-in-firebug

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to create the .map files when transpiling from TypeScript to Javascript. 
Just include the property "sourceMap": true in the compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json and you're done!